# Is getline is as same as gets?

Tags: c++

Okay so my question is simple..

We all know that how bad the `gets` is in `C` & hence the advice is to use `fgets`.

Now in `C++` we use `std::string s` and `std::getline(std::cin, s)`..Now my question is that does getline() has the same boundary checking issue like gets()..

If yes then for `char input[100]` & `cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));` will work for char array but while using string can I write this?

`std::string s;` & `cin.getline(s, s.capacity());` ...is this appropriate or something else can I write??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `getline` does not have the same issues as `gets`. The function has a reference to the string, and so can call the string's `size` and `capacity` member functions for boundary checking purposes. However, it doesn't need to do that, because it also has access the string's resizing member functions, such as `push_back`, `resize` or `operator+=`, which will handle boundary checking automatically, reallocating when necessary.

Comment: but then why the `cin.getline(s, s.capacity())` gives the error?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: The `getline` member function only works with char arrays, not `std::string`. Use the non-member function for `std::string`. -- `std::getline(std::cin, s);`

Comment: So you meant that when we use the overloaded `operator+=` it dynamically increases the memory ?? That means, the data is present in heap ?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar: Yes, it will allocate extra memory if the capacity is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

get() leaves the delimiter in the queue thus letting you able to consider it as part of the next input. getline() discards it, so the next input will be just after it.

If you are talking about the newline character from a console input,it makes perfectly sense to discard it, but if we consider an input from a file, you can use as "delimiter" the beginning of the next field.